# CSS table cell not filling 100% of the screen width

Tags: html, css

I have the following:

```
<div class="xx-row">
    <div class="background-image" style="background-image: url('<?php echo theme('background_image', 'url'); ?>');">
        <div class="yy-column">

        </div>
    </div>  
</div>

.xx-row {
    display: table;
}

.yy-column {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

When viewing the page in full screen, for some reason the columns do not fill the width of the page. If I manually set the width it works but I don't want to do this. Setting the width to the 100% doesn't have any effect.

[image]

This is how I'd like it to look:

[image: Page]

Inspecting element, parent div looks OK and xx-row looks OK too, the background image after the xx-row also looks fine and stretches the screen. So it's the columns that are the issue, if I set it to 100% that fills up the screen but the left column takes up about 80% of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be some problems with width of some parent element of your `.row`. Inspect all parent elements, I think - you will find the guilty one. Although inspect `.column` and `.row` classes in console, maybe there are some other css frameworks that can affect it (the `.column` and `.row` names are vary common, uses in Bootstrap etc.). Don't forget to add `width: 100%;` to your `table` element.

**UPDATED**

The main mistake was the `.column`'s direct parent was not `.row`, but `.background-image`. Rewrited the code according to right `display: table` and `display: table-cell`, the elements should be direct relatives.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.xx-row {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.background-image {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.yy-column {
  display: table-cell;
}

.one {
  background: #333;
}

.two {
  background: #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="xx-row">
    <div class="background-image" style="background-image: url('<?php echo theme('background_image', 'url'); ?>');">
        <div class="yy-column one">

        </div>
        <div class="yy-column two">

        </div>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: modified my original post as I'm using different column and row class names. Inspecting element, parent div looks OK and xx-row looks OK too, the background image after the xx-row also looks fine and stretches the screen. So it's the columns that are the issue, if I set it to 100% that fills up the screen but the left column takes up about 80% of the screen.

Comment: Updated, please, take a look.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know why column's immediate parent has to be row for it to work correctly?

Comment: `display: table` should be a direct parent or `display: table-cell`